# How to get glmnet to work for proportions as response variable?

Tags: logistic, proportion, data-preprocessing, glmnet, weighted-regression

I am trying to run a penalized logistic regression in `R`. My response variables are proportions (they are winning percentages for a sports team), and I have the number of total games played by each team.

My impression from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.1-3/topics/glmnet) is that I should be able to run `glmnet` to get penalized logistic regression for these proportions, as long as I make the weights the number of games played.

However, when I run this code

```
fit = glmnet(mat, wins/games ,family = "binomial", weights = games)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs, : 
one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not allowed
```

This error seems to be the standard error for trying to run logistic regression on non-binary responses. But the documentation really does seem to say that proportions should be okay. I've checked and my vectors of wins and games really seem to be fine:

```
wins = 16  8 10  7  7  6  5  2  1  1  1  1  0 11 11  5  5  4  3  3  2  1  0  9  6  4  4  3  2  1  0  0
games = 24 16 15 14 12 11  9  6  5  5  5  5  4 19 17 11 10 10  7  7  6  5  4 18 11 11 10  7  6  5  4  4
```

I haven't found anything online that's particularly helpful. I've found sources (like the documentation) that say that proportions should be possible, but no examples actually doing it. I've also found examples where someone fits data that is wildly non-binary (and not even a proportion), thereby resulting in this error message.

Any help or insight into what is going wrong, or even a minimal working example (I don't include mat because I'm using a ton of predictors), would be so appreciated!!

Comment: Try `family = quasibinomial()`.

Comment: quasibinomial is not even an option in glmnet

Comment: Yes it is. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing the proportion, you'd be better off using the gaussian family.  Right now, glmnet is treating the outcome as a continuous outcome, which is why you're getting that error.  The continuous outcome is incompatible with the binomial family.

One way to make this work is to make your outcome a matrix with columns for wins/loss.  Here is an example in R

```
library(glmnet)

X = matrix(rnorm(2*100), ncol=2)
b = c(2, -2)
eta = X%*%b - 1
p = plogis(eta)
n = rep(10, length(p))
# Simulate y wins in n games
y = rbinom(100, n, p)
# One column for wins, one for games minus wins (or loss)
outcome = cbind(y, n-y)
glmnet(X, outcome, family = binomial())
```

Comment: Isn't it a problem that a gaussian family might predict win percentages greater than one or less than zero?  Or, in the case of wins and losses, more wins than number of games played?  You also miss out on the other benefits of the logit.  For example, if the benefit of adding a 50 home run player is +0.5 on the link function, this translates to +12% win percentage for a .500 team (inv.logit(0.5) - inv.logit(0)) but (sensibly) +4% win percentage for a .880 team (inv.logit(2.5) - inv.logit(2.0)).

Comment: @Aurthur The Gaussian model could respect the boundaries were the win/loss ratios not too close to the boundary.  People do this all the time with the linear probability model.  I'm not saying its a better alternative, but it is an alternative if OP wants to proceed with passing a proportion.

Comment: Understood.  Is there a reason glm and glmnet and don't handle this?  Seems like it would be straightforward to formulate a maximum likelihood estimator for this case.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not completely sure.  The problem is likely the weight of the observation.  Clearly 5 successes out of 10 should be weighted less than 500 our of 1000.  Its unclear how much weight should be given without the number of trials.

Comment: Fair enough, but why does the documentation for glmnet say that it can handle proportions?

Comment: @seeker_after_truth Because glmnet can handle proportions, you're just not passing them in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.1-3/topics/glmnet) you link to  says

> response variable. Quantitative for family="gaussian", or family="poisson" (non-negative counts). For family="binomial" should be either a factor with two levels, or a **two-column** matrix of counts or **proportions** (the second column is treated as the target class; for a factor, the last level in alphabetical order is the target class). For family="multinomial", can be a nc>=2 level factor, or a matrix with nc columns of counts or proportions. For either

(my bold) - you need to pass a 2 column matrix of the proportions.

In any case, consider how you want crossvalidation to work.. are you sampling teams uniformly or games.